# Removing duplicates rows by max date on ordered table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have the table Example Table with the following data

Example Table

| ID | DATE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2021-04-13 21:39:00.569000 | ABC |
| 8 | 2020-12-17 16:49:17.903000 | ABC |
| 7 | 2020-12-16 16:49:17.903000 | ABC |
| 6 | 2020-06-09 09:55:52.005000 | WER |
| 5 | 2020-06-09 09:55:52.004000 | WER |
| 4 | 2020-06-08 09:48:43.318000 | YTG |
| 3 | 2020-06-05 14:51:42.860000 | YTG |
| 2 | 2020-04-28 13:58:30.972000 | YTG |
| 1 | 2020-04-25 13:58:30.972000 | ABC |

And I want to get for every distinct NAME in the table it's has max date until found a diffrent NAME. So the result set must be as the following

Expected Output

| ID | DATE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2021-04-13 21:39:00.569000 | ABC |
| 6 | 2020-06-09 09:55:52.005000 | WER |
| 4 | 2020-06-08 09:48:43.318000 | YTG |
| 1 | 2020-04-25 13:58:30.972000 | ABC |

I tried sql query as below and got no result.

```
select NAME
from
(
  select NAME, max(DATE) - min(DATE) as diff
  from Example_Table
  group by NAME
) ex
order by diff desc;
```

Comment: Your query and expected output have nothing to do with each other. Do you want the max date for each name (your query, at least kind of) or the full row for that max date for each name (your expected output)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(name) over (order by date) as next_name
      from t
     ) t
where next_name is null or next_name <> name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it was useful for my case.